# HTML and CSS on nested divs

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble building some nested divs.

I have the following structure:

```
<div id="master">
    <div id="number">
        <p>123</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Some content here.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**You can take a look at a visual example here:** [image]

- The first div, which is "master", is there just to keep things
  organized.
- The div called "content" will be filled with some
  information from a database, so it cannot have any fixed height.
  However, a minimum height can be specified.
- The div called "number"
  has to be flexible in order to follow the "content" div's height and
  show the number aligned to the center of it (text-align and
  vertical-align).

The image that I've uploaded can help you understanding what I need. I've been trying a lot of CSS codes, but none of them worked.

**EDIT 1:**

This was the closest I've got to make it work (but the number didn't get aligned vertically to the middle of the div).

```
#master {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#number {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle; /* DOESN'T WORK */
    text-align: center;
}

#content {
    float: left;
    width: 450px;
}
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: You should use Javascript

Comment: What you want is for the master div to inherit its height from the content div, and for the number div to simply use the master's height. But that is the reverse of how property inheritance normally works in css. I've perused the CSS standard searching for a way to do this, and unfortunately, I don't think it can be done (easily), at least without adding some javascript.

Comment: @jpaugh exactly that. Well... I'll see what I can do here.

Comment: Yeah, if you had a fixed height for the content, it would work. I was trying to align an editor and preview window with this. Eventually, I just used absolute positioning to take up the whole screen. I wanted a non-js solution, so I didn't consider a js work-around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try CSS tables:

```css
#master {
    display: table-row;
}
#number, #content {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

And then,

```css
#number {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
#content {
    background: blue;
    width: 450px;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kv7yqry3/1/)

Comment: Depending on the browser, you may have to add a corresponding {display: table} wrapper to get it to pick up the table-row and table-cell.

Comment: A similar solution could be obtained but absolutely positioning the content top: 50%; then going margin-top take half the height of the element. But you'd need to know the height...

Comment: @RichRemer OP contemplates using flexboxes, so I don't think old browsers that need `display: table` matters him.

Comment: @MaraisRossouw Moreover, absolute positioning removes the element from the normal flow of the document, which may be undesirable. A good alternative to CSS tables is [Centering in the unknown](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)

Comment: It really depends on the desired outcome, see in some cases flow isnt care about so the solution will work.